# Nodejs async.whilst() runs only one time

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a script to batch process some text documents and insert them into a mysql database.  I'm trying to use the async library because using a standard while loop blocks the event queue and prevents the insert queries from getting run until all are generated.  Since that may take 10 minutes or more, I get a timeout.  So, I am trying to use async to avoid blocking the main thread.  However, it's not working as expected.  When I run the simplest form of the code below, using `node test.js`, in the command line, it only executes once, instead of infinitely.  It seems like the computer is terminating the node process early since it is non-blocking.  This, of course, is not what I want.  Why is this, and how can I get it to work correctly?

```
//this code should run forever, constantly printing "working". However it only runs once.
var async = require('async')    
async.whilst(function(){return true},function(){console.log("working")})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter for [`whilst()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) is a function that *takes in a callback* that needs to be called when the current iteration is "done."

So if you modify the code this way, you'll get what you're expecting:

```
var async = require('async');
async.whilst(function() {
  return true
}, function(cb) {
  console.log("working");
  cb();
});
```